Jenkins upgrade: 2.319.3.4 to 2.462.1.3 version is failing with error: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: jenkins/security/QueueItemAuthenticatorMonitor
I have a CloudBees jenkins server with v: 2.319.3.4 on RHEL and I am trying to upgrade it to v2.462.1.3.
Post upgrade, I am stuck at below error and not able to get through this.
Please let me know if any of you faced similar error:
    java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: jenkins/security/QueueItemAuthenticatorMonitor
    at PluginClassLoader for cloudbees-administrative-monitors//com.cloudbees.jenkins.plugins.administrative_monitors.CloudbeesAdministrativeMonitorExtensionFilter.allows(CloudbeesAdministrativeMonitorExtensionFilter.java:26)
    at jenkins.ExtensionFilter.isAllowed(ExtensionFilter.java:81)
    at hudson.ClassicPluginStrategy.findComponents(ClassicPluginStrategy.java:363)
    at hudson.ExtensionList.load(ExtensionList.java:384)
    at hudson.ExtensionList.ensureLoaded(ExtensionList.java:320)
    at hudson.ExtensionList.iterator(ExtensionList.java:172)
    at jenkins.model.Jenkins.launchTcpSlaveAgentListener(Jenkins.java:1355)
    at jenkins.model.Jenkins.<init>(Jenkins.java:1020)
    at hudson.model.Hudson.<init>(Hudson.java:86)
    at hudson.model.Hudson.<init>(Hudson.java:82)
    at hudson.WebAppMain$3.run(WebAppMain.java:248)
Caused: hudson.util.HudsonFailedToLoad
    at hudson.WebAppMain$3.run(WebAppMain.java:262)



jenkins v2.46x might need jdk 17 or higher.
https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/platform-information/support-policy-java/


Hi PeterLee, thanks for your reply. Note that, I am able to get the Jenkins process up and running. I am hitting above error on accessing jenkins from browser.
FYR, updated screenshot in the question.
